# Sharing assertions inside page object methods

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to create a method within a page object that performs a specific test which I'll end up using often. I've followed the [documentation example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#using-test-controller-outside-of-test-code) but that's for typing/click, and maybe can't work with `expect`?

```
AssertionError: expected undefined to be truthy
```

That error specifically points to this line inside my test:

```
await t.expect(await page.nameTextInput.isRequired()).ok()
```

It's calling the `isRequired` check inside a "TextInputFeature" I've used inside my page object model:

```
export default class TextInputFeature {
    constructor(model) {
        this.input = AngularJSSelector.byModel(model);
        this.label = this.input.parent().prevSibling('label');
        this.asterisk = this.label.find('.required');
    }

    async isRequired() {
        await t
            .expect(this.input.hasAttribute('required')).ok()
            .expect(this.asterisk.exists).ok();
    }
}
```

EDIT: The following "works":

```
await t
      .expect(...)
      .click(...)
      .expect(...)
await page.racTextInput.isRequired();
await t
      .expect(...)
```

...but my goal is to allow chaining:

```
await t
      .expect(...)
      .click(...)
      .expect(page.racTextInput.isRequired()).ok()
      .expect(...)
```

Answer (score 3):

I found some mistakes in your code. Please check it.
1) The `isRequired` method returns nothing, and that's why you got `undefined`.
2) I think you don't need to wrap the `isRequired` method in a separate `expect` call. It should be enough to write only `await page.nameTextInput.isRequired()`
3) You missed the `t` parameter in the `isRequired` method, however, I think it's just a typo

UPDATED:

Test page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Name
    <div class="required">*</div>
    </label>
    <input required="required" type="text" id="name">
</body>
</html>
```

Test code:

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

class TextInputFeature {
    constructor () {
        this.input    = Selector('input#name');
        this.label    = Selector('label');
        this.asterisk = this.label.find('.required');
    }

    async isRequired () {
        const hasRequiredAttribute = await this.input.hasAttribute('required');
        const asteriskExists       = await this.asterisk.exists;

        return hasRequiredAttribute && asteriskExists;
    }
}

fixture`fixture`
    .page`../pages/index.html`;

test(`test`, async t => {
    const inputFeature = new TextInputFeature();

    await t
        .click(inputFeature.label)
        .expect(await inputFeature.isRequired()).ok()
        .click(inputFeature.label);
});
```

Comment: I've followed the example, but I've also seen the same approach [here](https://testcafe-discuss.devexpress.com/t/chaining-page-objects-functionality/1120). 1) The async method uses `await` and doesn't need a return, in fact eslint calls me out for doing so 2) I want it to be chained, that's my goal. 3) `t` is imported, not passed as an argument, per the documentation.

Comment: I've modified my answer to demonstrate the approach which I would recommend